# Save meta field in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a new select field to the page properties sidebar, but I am having trouble getting it to save the value.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<?php

function addMyMeta() {
    add_meta_box( 'my_custom_metabox', 'My Meta', 'setMyMeta', 'page', 'side', 'default' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'addMyMeta' );

function setMyMeta() {
    global $page;
    $value = get_post_meta( $page->ID, 'my_custom_metabox', true );
    ?>
    <fieldset>
        <select name="my_custom_metabox" id="my_custom_metabox" autocomplete="off">
            <option value="">Default</option>
            <option value="my-value" <?php if($value == 'my-value') {echo ' selected ';}; ?>>My Value</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
}

function saveMyMeta( $page_id, $page ) {
    if ( !isset( $_POST['my_custom_metabox'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $page->ID, 'my_custom_metabox', $_POST['my_custom_metabox'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'saveMyMeta', 1, 2 );

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `global $page;` to `global $post;` and  `$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_custom_metabox', true );`

```
function setMyMeta() {
    global $post;
   
   $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_custom_metabox', true );
    ?>
    <fieldset>
        <select name="my_custom_metabox" id="my_custom_metabox" autocomplete="off">
            <option value="">Default</option>
            <option value="my-value" <?php if($value == 'my-value') {echo ' selected ';}; ?>>My Value</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Ok, tried that, and also changed `page` to `post` in `saveMyMeta` but when I refresh it still goes back to default?

Comment: No. It will work fine when you refresh.

Comment: Did you change this line `get_post_meta( $post->ID,`?

Comment: Also change `if ( !isset( $_POST['my_custom_metabox'] ) ) {` to `if ( isset( $_POST['my_custom_metabox'] ) ) {`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `isset` instead of `!isset` in `saveMyMeta` function. Why would you want to run the `update_post_meta` if the value is not even set?

I prefer to add meta boxes using OOP because it's easy and saves you from having to worry about naming collisions in the global namespace.

**Things to consider using while adding meta boxes:**

1. [wp_nonce_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_field/) to validate that the contents of the form came from the location on the current site and not somewhere else.
2. [selected()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/selected/) for select fields.
3. [array_key_exists()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_key_exists.asp) to check if the key exists.
4. Sanitizing the values before saving or updating by using: [sanitize_text_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/), [sanitize_textarea_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_textarea_field/), [intval()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_var_intval.asp), [floatval()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_var_floatval.asp) etc.
5. Adding `post_type` suffix to [save_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/) action hook. in your case it will be `save_post_page`.

**Here is the full OOP code:**

```
abstract class My_Custom_MetaBox {

  /**
   * Set up and add the meta box.
   */
  public static function add() {

    add_meta_box(
      'my_custom_metabox', // Unique ID
      'My Meta', // Box title
      [ self::class, 'html' ], // Content callback, must be of type callable
      'page', // Post type
      'side', // The context within the screen where the box should display
      'default' // Priority
    );

  }

  /**
   * Display the meta box HTML to the user.
   */
  public static function html( $post ) {

    // Add an nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field('my_custom_meta_box', 'my_custom_meta_box_nonce');

    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_my_custom_metabox', true);

    ?>
      <fieldset>
        <select name="my_custom_metabox" id="my_custom_metabox" autocomplete="off">
          <option value="" <?php selected($value, ''); ?>>Default</option>
          <option value="my-value" <?php selected($value, 'my-value'); ?>>My Value</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>
    <?php

  }

  /**
   * Save the meta box selections.
   */
  public static function save( int $post_id ) {

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( !isset($_POST['my_custom_meta_box_nonce']) ) {
      return $post_id;
    }

    $nonce = $_POST['my_custom_meta_box_nonce'];

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'my_custom_meta_box') ) {
      return $post_id;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted,
    // so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
      return $post_id;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
      if ( !current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id) ) {
        return $post_id;
      }
    } else {
      if ( !current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ) {
        return $post_id;
      }
    }

    // Saving or Updating the data
    if ( array_key_exists('my_custom_metabox', $_POST) ) {
      $selected_value = sanitize_text_field($_POST['my_custom_metabox']);
      update_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_custom_metabox', $selected_value);
    }

  }

}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', ['My_Custom_MetaBox', 'add'] );
add_action( 'save_post_page', ['My_Custom_MetaBox', 'save'] );
```